# Dash callback function seems to have more inputs than possible

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I was doing IBM's data sci cert and I encountered a dash callback function that has two inputs, but the function itself has 7 inputs. How is this possible? The function is posted below.

@

```
app.callback( [Output(component_id='plot1', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot2', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot3', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot4', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot5', component_property='children')],
           [Input(component_id='input-type', component_property='value'),
            Input(component_id='input-year', component_property='value')],
           # REVIEW4: Holding output state till user enters all the form information. In this case, it will be chart type and year
           [State("plot1", 'children'), State("plot2", "children"),
            State("plot3", "children"), State("plot4", "children"),
            State("plot5", "children")`enter code here`
            ])

# Add computation to callback function and return graph
def get_graph(chart, year, children1, children2, c3, c4, c5):
```

Comment: The function take as input both `Input` and `State` callback from Dash so 7 is correct